# Fixing the height of a rectangle with a variable height TABLIX in rdlc

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-tablix

I have made invoice bill using rdlc. Invoice bills contains items. I want fixed rectangle size so that my items in tablix will fit into rectangle..Currently space is generated below tablix so section below rectangle is growing below..how do i fix rectangle size so that tablix will perfectly fit into rectangle regardless of number of rows in tablix..

Answer (score 0):

from the report properties, set `CanGrow` to `False` for both row and column

Comment: thanks for suggestion..After setting this i still got same issue..anything else can i do?

Comment: @LONG cannot find CanGrow in tablex properties